# RabbitMQ subscription getting duplicate messages when we use autoscaling subscription service

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, mqtt

I am using RabbitMQ for my IOT device to push data to server. From RabbitMQ am using nodejs service to subscribe data from particular topic.  For larger availability am using auto scaling for this service . When the service will scale based on its requirement it may be run in 2 or 3 instances. Because this 2 or 3 instances it will subscriber same messages from topic in multiple times. How can i prevent this (Multiple instances subscribing same topic don't get duplicates). One instance read message should remove from RabbitMQ topic how can i solve this ?

Please suggest:

My code this like this:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var clientId = 'mqttjs_' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8)
var client = mqtt.connect({
    clientId: clientId,
    host: "mqtt.host.co",
    port: 8883,
    'username': "user_name",
    'password': "password",
    protocol: 'mqtt.MQTTv311',
    resubscribe: true
});
// for topics starting at topic_name/
client.subscribe('topic_name/#', { qos: 0 })
```

Comment: BTW, The MQTT Node.JS module will auto-generate a clientId for you if it is not in the connect options.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something called Shared Subscriptions. This allows groups of clients to subscribe to a topic and any given message will only be delivered to one of the group. You can find a more detailed description of Shared Subscriptions [here](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-load-balancing-with-shared-subscriptions/)

Shared Subscriptions is part of the MQTT v5 spec, but some brokers had propitiatory implementations included as additions to their MQTT v3.x builds.

I'm not sure if RabbitMQ supports Shared Subscriptions as I've not been any doc or it when I've looked.

Comment: RabbitMQ don't have shared subscription . Any other option available in RabbitMQ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is provide for scaling of the RabbitMQ broker(s). Autoscaling will just launch multiple RabbitMQ instances and mess up your messaging bus...as you found out.  If you need to scale out more brokers to support more clients, you need to look at RabbitMQ Clustering: https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html

Comment: Don't have any issue with RabbitMQ clustering. I facing issue in subscription service clustering